# Why is data not going through the def dataframe()?

Tags: python, database, dataframe, sqlite

I am learning to add python data to my sqlite.
It works perfectly in other examples I have found online, but for some reason it doesn't in this one. No tables are created on the DB.
I have checked every line of the code and the last output I get is at multi.
So I am thinking that the error may be in the createframe.
What are the ties of the def createframe(msg): to the preceding code? I only see association with code after. So I am stuck with troubleshooting this. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
########################SECTION IMPORTS########################
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
import ta
import numpy as np
import time
import yfinance
from tqdm import tqdm
from binance import Client, AsyncClient, ThreadedWebsocketManager, ThreadedDepthCacheManager
client = Client('Client_API', 'Secret_API')
import websocket
bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
client = Client()
############CREATING A LOCAL DB ENGINE#########################
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///CryptoDB.db')
############FILTERING COIN FORMAT##############################
info = client.get_exchange_info()
symbols = [x['symbol']for x in info ['symbols']]
exclude = ['UP', 'DOWN', 'BEAR', 'BULL']
non_lev = [symbol for symbol in symbols if all(excludes not in symbol for excludes in exclude)]
relevant = [symbol for symbol in symbols if non_lev if symbol.endswith('USDT')
multi = [i.lower() +'@kline' for i in relevant]
############TRANSLATING VALUES FROM BINANCE TO A DATAFRAME######
def createframe(msg):
    df = pd.DataFrame([msg['data']])
    df = df.loc[:,['s', 'E', 'p']]
    df.columns = ['symbol', 'Time', 'Price']
    df.Price = df.Price.astype(float)
    df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='ms')
    return df
############STREAMING DATA TO SQL DB############################
async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ms = bm.multiplex_socket(multi)
    async with ms as tscm:
        while true:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            if res:
                frame = createframe(res)
                frame.to_sql(frame.symbol[0], engine, if_exist='append', index=False)

    await client.close_connection()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    lop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "going through"? What exactly do you think should happen, and what exactly appears to happen instead? If you think something is *not* happening that should, *why* do you think so?

Comment: "So I am thinking that the error may be in the createframe." Well, did you try to *test* this hypothesis? For example: when do you think `createframe` should get called? *Does* it get called then? When it's called, what *should be* the value of `msg`? What *is* the value of `msg`? And so on.

Comment: Not sure if this would solve the problem, but you could try to use `pd.DataFrame(data=[msg['data']])`. Also make sure the data you're passing to this function is correct.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you. My naive interpretation of the events is that, each new statement is taking data from the previous one and transforming it a step closer to what we want to achieve.
Then, when it comes to the dataframe statement, I do not see it has any references to the previous lines.

I do see that on the def main() it is tied to frame "frame = createframe(res)"

That is my uneducated way of understanding python at the moment.

Comment: So in this case, I see createframe has the purpose to transform the data into a specific final format to be stored on the DB. I do not see a source from where it is getting the data, but I do see the output being called on the "async def main()".
I assumed that if I enter every line of code all the way to dataframe and the call "dataframe(msg)" I should get the data that is actually going to be sent to the sql.

Comment: @Alexandru DuDu, thank you. your code did not change the current behaviour.
All the preceding statements to createframe work. So I'm troubleshooting the first function that is not, which is the createframe.

Comment: Also, the connection, as seen in Jupyter, remains busy, so the stream subscription to the websocket is successful. That was also a clue pointing to troubleshoot the createframe, but I haven't done a great job so far.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on this line "multi = [i.lower() +'@kline' for i in relevant]"
@kline does not provide the right data.

The solution is to change to @trade.

"multi = [i.lower() +'@trade' for i in relevant]"